# How did I get EXP for throwing my Dumud?

Tags: palworld

I needed 1 EXP to level up, and somehow throwing my Dumud at the ground at my base did it?

And then immediately threw more of my Pals against the ground, and somehow I got EXP for doing it to my Dumud for a second and third time? But it doesn't happen all the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pals performing tasks at your base, such as crafting, planting, or harvesting, rewards XP.

There is no XP from throwing your spheres at the ground -- you were simply reaping the benefits from your hard-working laborers by proximity!

Comment: Yeah, just watched a Harvesting happen, and I did get EXP from it! I just never noticed the notification until now, that I'm paying attention!